# ngOnChanges is not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

Hello i am new to angular and having a little issue, here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input, SimpleChange, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Sensor } from '../../shared/sensor.model';
import { MessageService } from '../../shared/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sensor-list',
  templateUrl: './sensor-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sensor-list.component.css']
})
export class SensorListComponent implements OnInit {

  sensors:Sensor[]=[];
  sensorsId : number[]=[];
  @Input() messages:JSON[]=[];
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.messages=this.messageService.getMqttdata();
      console.log("updating Sensors sources")
    },5000);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes SimpleChange }) {
      console.log("sources has been modified")
  }
```

In ngOnInit i gather data every 5 seconds and store those  into my messages variable which is an Input() so it should trigger the ngOnChanges every 5 secs ? what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Input` properties are supposed to be something that the parent of this component will pass it. It isn't supposed to be received from a service right inside this component.

If that was the case, this service call should reside in the parent component that is using this component.

So if you have a component(say with `selector`: `app-home`), then inside the template of `app-home`, you'll be using `app-sensor-list` and you'll pass `messages` from there.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<app-sensor-list [messages]="messages"></app-sensor-list>
```

Again inside the app-home component's TypeScript class, you'll make the service call:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.messages=this.messageService.getMqttdata();
      console.log("updating Sensors sources")
    },5000);
}
```

Comment: my service is defined in the parent component providers so should i get the data into the parent component then bind the parent's related attribute to the one i want to trigger on changes ? if i am right can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: Consider marking it as a solution if this solved your query.